# Read JSON property name from JsonContract

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net

I've got a DTO which is serialized to JSON. I need to know the name of the property as it will appear in the JSON. I have the appropriate `IContractResolver`, but I'm not sure how to go from this to the final property name.

I've used `GetResolvedPropertyName`, which is a start but not an end. For example, since it takes a string as argument it can't look up e.g. `JsonPropertyAttribute` on the property. There may be other cases where it doesn't do the complete job.

How can I get the final property name, given that I have the `PropertyInfo` and the `ContractResolver`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand *why* you'd need to do this, but, assuming your `IContractResolver` derives from the `DefaultContractResolver`, you can get the property names like this:

```
JsonObjectContract contract = (JsonObjectContract)resolver.ResolveContract(typeof(DTO));
var dict = contract.Properties.ToDictionary(p => p.UnderlyingName, p => p.PropertyName);

Console.WriteLine("Serialized property names will be: ");
foreach (var kvp in dict)
{
    Console.WriteLine(kvp.Key + " => " + kvp.Value);
}
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/RnwnRc